# How to write an Advanced Query which gets the same results as the simple query option

Tags: qgis

Working with my data set on Late Woodland Village reanalysis in QGIS, the previous question was somewhat answered by defining the issue as a many to one. As a work-around, I summarized the info into comma separated values within cells. For instance, temper would be SC, LS, H, SF as possible combinations. Likewise I have created a template of decorative attributes numbered from 1-77.

When I do a simple query for SC, it gives me all 15. But in Advanced Query, I get different answers.

In Dec Attributes, if I set the sample as 3, it gives me all of the strings with 3 in them, rather than just 3.

The first question is how do I select one string set out of all the others and the second question is how I select SC from Temper and 35 from Dec Attributes at the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember, simple query implements the LIKE comparison. Therefore, a simple query for 'SC' in the "Temper" attribute would equal the following advanced query:

```
"Temper" LIKE '%SC%'
```

Similarly, to filter by two attributes at the same time:

```
"Temper" LIKE '%SC%' AND "Dec" = 35
```

if "Dec" contains only numerical values and not a list of values like "Temper".

Comment: OK, my syntax was incomplete for the first ones, basically I was using either ' or % but not both. But for the second question, under Dec, there are 77 potential numerical values, and if I am looking for 6 only, it gives me all occurrences of 6 as in 16, 26, etc. How do i get 6 only. I've tried dec = 6 and get the entire group. Thanks

Comment: @LyleBrowning Please post a screenshot of your attribute table.

Comment: Based on your answer, I changed the numbers to text, put a zero in front of those below 10 and it now works, as a workaround until I can work out the pivot text or many to one approaches suggested. Thanks

Comment: Where does one post a screenshot?

Comment: @LyleBrowning edit your question. you can put it there